# Creating stored procedure with 2 different sets of data (using value from first data as parameter for 2nd data)

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables which contains the following :

table1

```
start | end | pcs 
0840   1030   35
1040   1230   30
```

table2

```
timestamp | line
0841
0842
1041
1042
```

I would want to compute the total count of each time of table2 from time range from table1?

I hope someone could get this,

thanks

Comment: Have you tried some query..?

Comment: Yes, but I was stucked on joining the 2 tables(actually the 2 sets of this table came from another complex sets of sql commands), The answer below game some basic idea and incorporated it on my result! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    t1.[start], t1.[end], count(*)
from table1 as t1
    left outer join table2 as t2 on t2.timestamp between t1.[start] and t1.[end]
group by t1.[start], t1.[end]
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67a2c/1)